# I am trying to create a multi-time-worked Timesheet

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, excel-365

I am trying to create a timesheet with multiple time in and time out slots.
The reason I am doing this is I currently work at a job where I am some days in the office from 9 AM - 11 AM, then back from 1 PM - 4 PM, and back on at night (Sometimes once, sometimes multiple times) and I want to better track my hours for myself.
I am trying to work out how many hours TOTAL time I have worked in a day, while making sure Sick, Holiday and Vacation are all blank.

Below is the code I am working with, but it comes up "TRUE" instead of the number of total hours worked.

**NOTE:**
Time in is in Columns C, E and H.
Time out is in Column C, F and I.
Sick is in Column M.
Holiday is in Column N.
Vacation is in Column O.

=IF((AND(B3="",M3<>"",N3<>"",O3<>"")),0,IF(AND(C3>B3,F3=E3),(C3-B3)*24,IF(AND(C3>B3,F3>E3,I3=H3),(C3-B3)+(F3-E3)*24,IF(AND(C3>B3,F3>E3,I3>H3),(C3-B3)+(F3-D3)+(I3-H3)*24,0))))

In full disclosure, this code was modified from two different timesheet spreadsheets found "free to download" on the internet, however, neither gave me what I need, and making slight modifications has failed to do so either.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

I have tried the above, along with another code(s) I don't wish to post as it would be a blatent copy/paste of someone else's work.

I am just expecting the TOTAL cell to show me a total hours count.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a typo in the description of the columns (you didn't say what column B is and column C is both IN and OUT time).

Is the following picture how you want your spreadsheet to look like:
[image]

This is the formula that I used:

```
=MAX(D3-C3,0) + MAX(F3-E3,0) + MAX(I3-H3,0) + 8/24*COUNTA(M3:O3)
```

The column P has this format: `[=0]"";[h]:mm;@`

If you want more details, or need help debugging your formula, upload your spreadsheet in OneDrive or equivalent, and I'll help you.